# node.js (core / framework)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, geddy

I have just completed reading & implementing the awesome "**The Node Beginner Book**" by **Manuel Kiessling**. Didn't find a better resource on node.js for a newbie like me. Now I need to make a full fledged application (something like a restaurant review website) with backend handled by node.js 
What should be my approach? core or framework(express/geddy)?
I would also need a nosql database like mongodb ? how do I incorporate that into my node app?
Should i also consider jade and stylus into my app?
**What should be my plan of action?**
I'm open to suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to start from express framework http://expressjs.com/

If you plan to use mongo database - use http://mongoose.com  ORM
If you plan to use SQL databases - use http://sequelizejs.com/

For dealing with users and authorization, you can use http://passportjs.org

Probably you can try to use my framework, build on top of expressJS
https://npmjs.org/package/hunt
it have a lot of important nodejs modules preconfigured, but i'm still working on documentation...

Anyway, take a look at http://expressjs.com/ first - this is mainstream - easy to use and minimalistic framework

Answer (score 0):

One of my previous question is very similar to yours, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640433/which-technology-stack-modules-frameworks-is-better-for-the-first-node-js-pro).

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787716/is-there-a-template-engine-for-node-js) more about templating engines.